# Gecko WebBrowser.DocumentComplete Event

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, gecko, readystate

I'm creating an application that contains "geckoWebBrowser" in c #. But I have to wait the complete loading a web page, and then continue to execute other instructions. there is something similar to geckowebbrowser1.DocumentComplete, but i don't know how to use this.

Please help me with my code:

```
                geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);

                // i want to perform below thing after web page load completes

                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                int i = listBox1.Items.Count;
                string str = Convert.ToString(i);
                label2.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event:

```
geckoWebBrowser1_OnDocumentCompleted(EventArgs e)
```

But remember this event can fire many times before same page ends loading... write the logic accordingly.